# Parsing a string containing any chars

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to get following to work. So I have strings that are inside parentheses. The strings can contain any characters, and hence the string that I want to parse can also contain parentheses. I think the regex currently matches also the last parentheses that is supposed to be matched by <~ ")", and thus the parsing fails. What am I missing here?

```
private def parser: Parser[Any] = a ~ b ~ c ^^ {
    <do stuff here>
}

private def a: Parser[String] = "\"[^\"]*\"".r | "[^(),>]*".r

private def b: Parser[String] = opt("(" ~> ".*".r <~ ")") ^^ {
    case Some(y) => y.trim
    case None       => ""
}

private def c: Parser[String] = rep(".@" ~> "[^>.]*".r) ^^ (new String(_).trim)
```

This is supposed to parse following kind of strings:

```
test0
test1.@attr
"test2"
"test3".@attr
test4..
test5..@attr
"test6..".@attr
"test7.@attr".@attr
test8(icl>uw)
test9(icl>uw).@attr
"test10..().@"(icl>uw).@attr
test11(icl>uw(agt>uw2,obj>uw3),icl>uw4(agt>uw5))
test12(icl>uw1(agt>uw2,obj>uw3),icl>uw4).@attr1.@attr2
test13(agt>thing,obj>role>effect)
```

So the "a" parser parses the string until open parentheses or .@attr part. "b" parser parses the characters inside optional parentheses. "c" parses the optional .@attrs.

Currently I get similar error on all test strings containing parentheses part:

```
11:07:44.662 [main] DEBUG - Parsed: test8()
11:07:44.667 [main] ERROR - FAILURE parsing: test8(icl>uw) -- `)' expected but `i' found
```

So I assume that the parser parsed the first part correctly, but failed when it saw the parentheses part.

Comment: You need to expand this question with (perhaps) a small **example** of what you are trying to do and what it is that is not working, as it just is not clear from the question, as it is currently formed.

For example: what should happen when getting the String input `(()`? What *does* happen? An error? Something unexpected?

Comment: Made the example a bit more clear. So essentially I want to parse anything  that's inside parentheses.

Comment: Regular languages (and consequently, regular expressions) cannot be used to parse nested parentheses: they are not expressive enough. You need to use another technique, using either recursion, or automata, or a parser generator.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution to parse nested structures is to use recursion, for example in the following fashion:

```
val parser= "regex".r
@tailrec
def extract(string:String,foundTokens:List[String]=List.empty):List[String]={
  parser.findFirstMatchIn(string) match {
  case Some(parser(matchedValue)) => extract(matchedValue,matchedValue::foundedTokens)
  case None=>foundTokens
}
```

Where basically at each call to the function, you append the found token to a list of results and you launch the function on the result of the match. When you do not find anymore you return the found token.

If multiple matches are possible inside each subtoken, then you should look for a procedure like this one:

```
def extract(string:String):Iterator[String]={
   parser.findAllIn(string).flatMap{
      item => extract(item)  
   } 
}
```